# Can I set pig.temp.dir to /user/USERNAME/tmp/pig?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, permissions, apache-pig, configuration-files

Hive can be configured with

```
hive.exec.scratchdir=/user/${user.name}/tmp/hive
```

Can I do something similar with Pig?  I have tried modifying the pig.properties file, but nothing seems to work.

```
pig.temp.dir=/user/${user.name}/tmp/pig <- Doesn't work
pig.temp.dir=/user/`whoami`/tmp/pig     <- Doesn't work
pig.temp.dir=/user/${user}/tmp/pig      <- Doesn't work
pig.temp.dir=/user/${username}/tmp/pig  <- Doesn't work
```

I could replace the pig command with an alias, but I am hoping to have the change enshrined in the configuration file.

```
pig -Dpig.temp.dir=/user/`whoami`/tmp/pig
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: We decided to use /tmp/ for the production system.  The reason this was an issue at all is because we are running MapR which seems to try to put the temp directories into the user directory, and succeeds with Hive, but not with Pig.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the pig temp dir from within a Pig script as follows:

`set pig.temp.dir /user/foo/tmp/pig;`

For small outputs, I think using the /tmp directory is fine, but for large outputs, I'd recommend users write to their personal directories.

Answer (score 0):

Not a configuration file solution, but you can bake this into the $PIG_HOME/bin/pig script:

```
PIG_OPTS="$PIG_OPTS -Dpig.temp.dir=/user/`whoami`/tmp/pig"
```

Comment: That definitely will work, but it's difficult to maintain on a production system.

Comment: Maintain in what sense? This only needs to be present on client machines, so whatever process you have to deliver your custom pig.properties, surely you can deliver the modified pig script in the same manner?